# AWS EC2 unreachable for SSH or HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

My AWS EC2 is not reachable by SSH or HTTP (the httpd service is running.) Both timeout. I can log in via the AWS Systems Manager. I set the security group inbound rules for the EC2 instance on port 22 and port 80  as 0.0.0.0/0 (I used to have port 22 as just my ip address but thought opening it up might help.) I have run the reachability analyzer from the internet gateway to the instance and it is successful so that would seem to indicate that the VPC, subnet and route table are configured correctly for inbound internet traffic right? What else can I look for?

Comment: Have you contact AWS support first ?

Comment: At my tier there is no technical support. Only billing support. I believe there are aws forums however.

Comment: You have to provide more info. Is your EC2 instance in a public subnet? Is the issue with this specific instacne only? What about any other instance in the same subnet?

Comment: You can add debugging to the ssh command with `ssh -vvv`. Please show us what it says.

Comment: Have you installed a web server on the instance? If you connect to the instance via Session Manager and run the command `curl localhost`, does it return a web page? This will test that the web server is running.

Comment: ssh with -vvv returns:
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/paulk/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 44.203.60.103 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 44.203.60.103 [44.203.60.103] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001ED219DF040
debug1: connect to address 44.203.60.103 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 44.203.60.103 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: I believe my EC2 instance is in a public subnet as it is connected to an internet gateway and has the default ACL / route table in and out 0.0.0.0/0  I only have one EC2 instance. I have all of my files I need so I could terminate this instance and start new with a fresh one. (That is actually what I did in order to upgrade from Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2.)

Comment: curl localhost in my session returns the contents of my index.html file sitting at /var/www/html/index.html

Comment: I have terminated this EC2 and launched a new one with a new security group and made sure that security group had open inbound rules. It is still unreachable so I'm thinking the problem is with the VPC. I guess I will try creating a new VPC with yet another new EC2 instance. My console is littered with terminated instances and old security groups that didn't work.

Comment: Tried multiple VPCs with new EC2 instances and that didn't work. I really have no idea where the problem is. I wish there was a checklist to go down to solve this that would bring me to the answer.

Comment: Thought I would add that when I log in via the Instance Connect (with my IAM user) I can verify httpd is running and I can also ping cnn.com so at least ping packets can make it out and back from the EC2.

Comment: For those following along this is a good checklist here (I have been through it and it has not lead me to a solution yet but still thought I would post):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout

Comment: So I used https://check-host.net/ with my outside ip address and it came back with 200 (OK) for HTTP and it also responded with the PING option. So I'm wondering if its a problem with my desktop client? (Although its not working from my iPhone either.) If anyone else would like to try and let me know the ip is 35.175.185.161  let me know if you can reach it. Thanks!

Comment: I found I could reach it from my iPhone when I turned my wifi off and used the cellular network. So I think the problem is with my VPC route table which has 0.0.0.0/0 pointed to the internet gateway but also has a few other lines which relate my ip address. Namely I think 173.66.0.0/16 was pointing to local. I've tried to remove it but it won't let me saying "There was an error editing routes. All changes have been reverted." So if I can't  delete this where should I point it so that I can reach my instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was a problem with the route table. It was too difficult or impossible to simply delete the bad line in the route table. Instead I had to create a new internet gateway/route table/vpc/subnet. (I am not exactly sure of the order of those...) I terminated my old instance and launched a new one onto the new vpc/subnet and set up a new security group with a fresh set of inbound rules. It seems like AWS's answer is to just create new things instead of trying to fix the old ones. Oh well. That's what worked for me.